# Talend ETL Job Error in tOracleOutput Component

Tags: java, etl, talend

I am a newbie to TalendETL and am using Talend Open Studio for Big Data version 5.4.1 . I have developed a simple Talend ETL job that picks up data from a csv file and inserts data into my local Oracle Database. Below is how my package looks:

[image]

The job returns an exception that `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` after the last record of the csv file. But I'm uncertain as to why it should return that in the first place? I checked out the solution given on this link: http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21644

But it doesn't seem to work at all. I have the latest driver for the oracle component and increasing/decreasing the commit size does not seem to affect it.

Can someone please help me out on this? Please let me know in case more information is needed.

P.S: The complete error log is below:-

```
Starting job Kaggle_Data_Load_Training at 09:31 25/06/2014.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3957
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tOracleOutput_1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32203
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2677)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:210)
    at test.kaggle_data_load_training_0_1.Kaggle_Data_Load_Training.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(Kaggle_Data_Load_Training.java:4360)
    at test.kaggle_data_load_training_0_1.Kaggle_Data_Load_Training.runJobInTOS(Kaggle_Data_Load_Training.java:4717)
    at test.kaggle_data_load_training_0_1.Kaggle_Data_Load_Training.main(Kaggle_Data_Load_Training.java:4582)
[statistics] disconnected
Job Kaggle_Data_Load_Training ended at 09:31 25/06/2014. [exit code=1]
```

Comment: instead of tOracleOutput if you use tFileoutputdelimited or any other DB output component - do you still get same ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try to decrease the commit size on the tOracleOutput component? I remember there is some kind of bug in 5.4.1. of TOS which resulted in this error. Therefore please lower commit size (let's say to 500) and see if the problem still exists. Here's more information about the bug: http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5931

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue in Talend 6.2.1

It can be resolved by changing updating `DB Version` in `metadata` of connection.

Same is confirmed on [Talend blog](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=53683)